# Iterating over numpy array rows in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to iterate over the rows of two numpy arrays in python, using the following for loop:

```
for i, j in range(X.shape[0]), range(y.shape[0]):
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I thought that by creating lists with the number of rows in each array I could iterate over X using the value of i, and over y using the value of j.

Could somebody please explain why this is not working, and how I could make it work instead? Thanks!

Comment: "iterate over the rows of two numpy arrays" is ambiguous. Do you want to iterate over the rows of two numpy arrays at the same time in one loop or do you want to iterate once over each row in Y for every row in X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not what you are looking to do.

To iterate over rows in X and rows in Y, you should use nested loops:

```
for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    for j in range(Y.shape[0]):
        func(i, j)
```

Having said this, I would strongly advise you use loops as a last resort. Try to vectorise functions where possible.

If you *must* loop, you may be able to improve performance by using `numba`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Everything's clear now. I am not very familiar with vectorizing functions, so I hadn't considered it, but I'll read about it and try it in the future.